# how to modified header and add it to download Curl c++

Tags: android, c++, curl

im try more time and search in google but no example show how to modified header data and add it to download using Curl. this is my method get header data response by server

```
bool getHeader(CURL* url, std::string name, std::string url_down,
    std::string savepath) {
bool result = false;
url = curl_easy_init();
FILE* headf;
CURLcode res;
std::string header_path = savepath + "/header.txt";
const char* url_d = url_down.c_str();
const char* save_header_down = header_path.c_str();
if (url) {
    headf = fopen(save_header_down, "wb");
    if (!headf) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(url);
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_URL, url_d);
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(url, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, headf);
    res = curl_easy_perform(url);
    LOGI("SDK: START DOWNLOAD HEADER");
    if (res == CURLE_OK) {
        LOGI("SDK: HEADER DOWNLOADED!");
        char* ct;
        char* ar;
        double *dTotal;
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(url, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(url, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD, &dTotal);            
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(url, CURLINFO_ACCEPT_RANGES, &ar);

        if((CURLE_OK == res) && ct){
            LOGI("SDK: HEADER CONTENT TYPE: %s", ct);
            LOGI("SDK: HEADER Content-Length: %d", dTotal);
            LOGI("SDK: HEADER Accept-Ranges: %s", ar);
        }
        result = true;
    }
    fclose(headf);
    curl_easy_cleanup(url);

  }
  return result;

}
```

you can see im not found CURLINFO_ACCEPT_RANGES in curl document [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)
any one can tell me how i can get accept-ranges of header in curl, modifed it and add to download. thanks

Comment: You're going to have to inspect the headers you received. Probably best to put them in a string in a callback function rather than writing them to a file.

Comment: yes @Galik, now i can put header content to string. but i want get accept-ranges, change it to resume download. Im find in the document of Curl but cannot see any fuction get accept-ranges of header

Comment: There is no function I know of, you'll have to extract that header from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with your function but here is an example of how I might go about capturing both the data and the headers from a HTTP request. Perhaps it will help you achieve what you are trying to do:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_func(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    if(userp)
    {
        std::string& s = *static_cast<std::string*>(userp);
        std::string::size_type len = size * nmemb;
        s.append(static_cast<char*>(buf), len);
        return nmemb;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode code = CURLE_OK;

    std::string url = "http://google.com/search?q=wibble";

    long timeout = 60; // seconds

    std::string data;
    std::string headers;

    if(CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_func))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, &headers))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))
    || CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str())))
    {
        std::cerr << curl_easy_strerror(code) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    if(CURLE_OK != (code = curl_easy_perform(curl)))
    {
        std::cerr << curl_easy_strerror(code) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Data:" << '\n';
    std::cout << data << '\n';

    std::cout << "Headers:" << '\n';
    std::cout << headers << '\n';

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: not effetive. Im use your example and Headers allway empty

Comment: sorry my bad. i have try again your solution and everything is ok. Thanks @Galik